# @NumberFormat Annotation not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Trying to show the currency symbol in JSP but I don't see it. Did my research and I just don`t know what more should I add to get it working. This is what I have.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Controller

```
@NumberFormat(style = Style.CURRENCY)
private Double value = 50.00;

@ModelAttribute("value")
@NumberFormat(style = Style.CURRENCY)
public Double getValue() {
    return value;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loadForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    ModelAndView instance 
    modelAndView.addObject("value", 100.00);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

JSP

```
<spring:bind path="value">
     <input type="text" name="${value}" value="${value}"/>
</spring:bind>

<spring:bind path="value">
     ${value}
</spring:bind>
```

Output

```
 <input type="text" name="value" value="100.0"/>

 100.0
```

Comment: Does the value show up, but just unformatted? Or does the value not show at all?

Comment: I have added the JSP output with @Kevin's suggested changes.

Comment: So it outputs but no formatting?

Comment: Yes. Missing currency symbol and seems like missing decimal position too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the string literal `value` for the name attribute instead of resolving it with EL

```
<spring:bind path="value">
     <input type="text" name="value" value="${value}"/>
</spring:bind>
```

Also, move the field value into a new object.  Currently I do not believe the code is using the field in the controller or the getter in the controller.

```
public class MyForm(){

    @NumberFormat(style = Style.CURRENCY)
    private Double value = 50.00;

    @ModelAttribute("value")
    @NumberFormat(style = Style.CURRENCY)
    public Double getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then add the object to the model in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loadForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    ModelAndView instance 
    modelAndView.addObject("myForm", new MyForm());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Then access via the jsp:

```
<spring:bind path="myForm.value">
     <input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}"/>
</spring:bind>

<spring:bind path="myForm.value">
     ${status.value}
</spring:bind>
```

The major issue at the moment with the code is that it is not using the field/accessor, it is simply placing a value in the model, which does not use any of the annotated fields/methods.

References: 
http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/08/using-spring-3-numberformat-annotation.html#.UOAO_3fghvA

[How is the Spring MVC spring:bind tag working and what are the meanings of status.expression and status.value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614729/how-is-the-spring-mvc-springbind-tag-working-and-what-are-the-meanings-of-statu)

Comment: I have it the way you are explaining but since it was not working I tried to make the example really simple for Spring annotation to work. But I can try making a very simple object like you say..with just one field.

Comment: Vow that worked. I did not see this anywhere. If possible can you add reference to `status` in you solution. It will be very helpful for others :)

Comment: @java_dude references added.

Comment: Question? What if it would have been a list of `new MyForm()`. How would that affect the JSP representation? Hint would help :)