# spring NumberFormat form submit doesn't work

Tags: number-formatting

I need to work with euro currency in my Spring MVC application.

My model has the following property declaration:

```
   @NumberFormat(style=Style.CURRENCY)
   private Float imp;
```

My jsp page has:

```
   <form:input path = "imp"/>
```

The result is corrent, for example the input field looks like "€ 45,2". That's ok!

Now, if I submit the form with the same value above (€ 45,2) I get the following error message:

Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Float for property detail.imp; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "€45,22"

I was expecting a conversion from the string to the Float type. Am I wrong?
Reading the articole
[Spring 3 @NumberFormat not working with form:input Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515027/spring-3-numberformat-not-working-with-forminput-tag)
 it seems I need to work with the FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean converter, but I also read many blogs where I understand what it shouldn't be necessary.

The conversion is bidirectional or the converter from the JSP to the model is "a must"?

Thanks all.