# What is the difference between spring:bind and form:errors?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have following form in Spring that is showing error messages. I am wondering when should I use spring:bind? What does that do that differentiate that with  ? I studied these pages [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614729/how-is-the-spring-mvc-springbind-tag-working-and-what-are-the-meanings-of-statu),[b](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/) but I am still puzzled.

**1**

```
<form:form method="post"
    action="http://localhost:8080/project/calculator/process"
    modelAttribute="keyPadForm">
        Name1: <form:input type="text" path="name1" />
        <form:errors path="name1" />
```

**2**

```
<form:form method="post"
    action="http://localhost:8080/project/calculator/process"
    modelAttribute="keyPadForm">
    <spring:bind path="name1">
        Name1: <form:input type="text" path="name1" />
        <form:errors path="name1" />
    </spring:bind>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your second case, `spring:bind` tag is obsolete, your first form

```
<form:form method="post"
    action="http://localhost:8080/project/calculator/process"
    modelAttribute="keyPadForm">
        Name1: <form:input type="text" path="name1" />
        <form:errors path="name1" />
```

is a sort of syntactic sugar, and the equivalent without using the `form` tag library, rather only the common HTML form tags, would be based on `spring:bind` and would look something like:

```
<spring:nestedPath path="keyPadForm">
   <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/project/calculator/process">
    <spring:bind path="name1">
        Name1:<input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}">
       <span class="fieldError">${status.errorMessage}</span>
    </spring:bind>
   </form>
</spring:nestedPath>
```

There are scenarios where you can make a difference, e.g. `form:input` is always a two way bind, so the value is sent to the server and the current value displayed, where as with `spring:bind` you can achieve a one way bind, only sending to server, by omitting the value e.g. `<input type="text" name="${status.expression}">`, but the main gist is that `form` tag library provides a more convenient bind related tags

Answer (score 3):

With `spring:bind`, you can use `${status.error}` to check if the `name1` field has an error, and display different CSS class conditionally.
The error message is still displayed via `form:errors`, but this way you get more controls.
for example:

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="userForm" action="${userActionUrl}">
    <spring:bind path="name">
    <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <label>Name</label>
        <form:input path="name" type="text" id="name" />
        <form:errors path="name" />
    </div>
    </spring:bind>
</form:form>
```

and you can refer to this [Spring MVC Form – Check if a field has an error](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-check-if-a-field-has-an-error/)